# JPA: No join method for Fetch interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Via JPA Criteria Api

- a `Join` can in turn be joined either via `Join.join(...)` or via `Join.fetch(...)`.
- but a `Fetch` in turn can only be joined via `Fetch.fetch(...)`:

What is the reason? Why an attribute of a fetched entity in turn can not be joined (without fetch)?

For example:

```
root.join(entity1_attribute, JoinType.INNER)
    .join(entity2_attribute, JoinType.INNER)
    .fetch(entity3_attribute, JoinType.INNER)
```

is possible.

But

```
root.join(entity1_attribute, JoinType.INNER)
    .fetch(entity2_attribute, JoinType.INNER)
    .join(entity3_attribute, JoinType.INNER) //<--
```

is not possible.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Fetch represents a join-fetch where as Join is a join with or without fetch

Comment: @SimonMartinelli I have added an example. I hope it makes it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

It is this way for the same reason that the JPQL BNF does not allow aliasing fetch joins, because nested fetches do not have to be supported according to the JPA specification. You can ask on the JPA mailing list or create an issue to request making `Fetch` extend `Join` or something like that if you want.